# Why is an area preserving diffeomorphism a symplectomorphism (in $R^2$)

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

Given this very simple sympletic vector space: $\left(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathrm{~d} x \wedge \mathrm{d} y\right)$, how can we show that an area preserving diffeomorphism $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defines a symplectomorphism?

I believe an area-preserving diffeomorphism is a diffeomorphism that preserves the Lebesgue measure (please correct me if this is not the case or if there is a better definition in the context of symplectic geometry), but given that is the case, how can we relate preserving Lebesgue measure to showing that $\mathrm{~d} x \wedge \mathrm{d} y(u,v)=\mathrm{~d} x \wedge \mathrm{d} y (f(u),f(v))$ which is the definition of symplectomorphism where f is our area-preserving diffeomorphism.

Comment: How rigorous are you trying to be? The Riemannian area form and symplectic form are equal in this case. So preserving one is the same as preserving the other.

Comment: You forgot an assumption on $f$ here.

Comment: You need to compute pullback?

Answer (score 3):

You have two different notions to define a volume, volume forms i.e. nowhere vanishing $n$ forms on an $n$ dimensional manifold, and measure from measure theory. If $\omega$ is a symplectic form on $M$ of dimension $2n$, then $\mathrm{Vol} = \frac{\omega^n}{n!}$ is a volume form on $M$. On $M = \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ endowed with its canonical symplectic form $\omega = \sum_{k = 1}^n dx_k \wedge dy_k$, we obtain the canonical volume form $\mathrm{Vol} = dx_1 \wedge dy_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n \wedge dy_n$ (this is why we divide by $n!$).

A symplectomorphism is a diffeomorphism $f$ such that $f^*\omega = \omega$ i.e.
$$
\forall x \in M, \forall (u,v) \in T_xM^2, \omega_{f(x)}(df(x)u,df(x)v) = \omega_x(u,v),
$$
and a volume preserving diffeomorphism is a diffeomorphism $f$ such that $f^*\mathrm{Vol} = \mathrm{Vol}$ i.e.
$$
\forall x \in M, \forall (u_1,\ldots,u_m) \in T_xM^m, \omega_{f(x)}(df(x)u_1,\ldots,df(x)u_m) = \omega_x(u_1,\ldots,u_m),
$$
where $m = \dim(M)$ ($= 2n$ in the symplectic case). In the case where $M$ is a symplectic surface, we simply have $\mathrm{Vol} = \omega$ hence the equivalence is trivial. In the general case, we only have symplectic $\Rightarrow$ volume preserving.

But seeing the form of your question, you are probably asking right now "what is the link between $f^*\mathrm{Vol} = \mathrm{Vol}$ and $f$ preaserving volume in the measure theory sens ?". Well, on any manifold $M$ equipped with a volume form $\mathrm{Vol}$ (whether or not it comes from a symplectic form), we can define a measure $\mu$ with,
$$
\mu(A) = \int_M \mathbf{1}_A \mathrm{Vol},
$$
on the open sets, extended to the Borel sets. In the case where $M = \mathbb{R}^n$ endowed with its canonical volume form, we obtain the Lebesgue measure. And we can prove that for all diffeomorphism $f$,
$$
f^*\mathrm{Vol} = \mathrm{Vol} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \forall A \subset M \textrm{ Borel}, \mu(f(A)) = \mu(A) \textrm{ and $f$ preserves orientation}.
$$
Indeed, assuming the left hand side $f$ preserves the orientation (trivial) and we have for all $A$ open (it is enough to show the right hand side for open sets),
\begin{align*}
\mu(f(A)) & = \int_M \mathbf{1}_{f(A)}\mathrm{Vol}\\
& = \int_M f^*\mathbf{1}_Af^*\mathrm{Vol} \textrm{ because $f^*\mathrm{Vol} = \mathrm{Vol}$,}\\
& = \int_M f^*(\mathbf{1}_A\mathrm{Vol})\\
& = \int_M \mathbf{1}_A\mathrm{Vol}\\
& = \mu(A).
\end{align*}
For the reciprocal, we may assume that $M = \mathbb{R}^m$ and the volume form is given by $\mathrm{Vol}_x = g(x)\det$ for some smooth $g : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+^*$ since we want to prove a local statement. Then, $\mu = g\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure (in your case, $g = 1$). Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $B_\varepsilon$ the ball of center $x_0$ and radius $\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. We have,
\begin{align*}
\mu(f^{-1}(B_\varepsilon)) & = \int_{f^{-1}(B_\varepsilon)} g(x) \, d\lambda\\
& = \int_{B_\varepsilon} g(f(x))\det(df(x)) \, d\lambda\\
& \textrm{ by change of variable ($\det(df(x)) > 0$ because $f$ preserves orientation),}\\
& \sim g(f(x_0))\det(df(x_0))\lambda(B_\varepsilon),
\end{align*}
when $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$. Similarly, $\mu(B_\varepsilon) \sim g(x_0)\lambda(B_\varepsilon)$. We deduce that $g(f(x_0))\det(df(x_0)) = g(x_0)$, which implies $(f^*\mathrm{Vol})_{x_0} = \mathrm{Vol}_{x_0}$, and it is true for all $x_0$ thus $f^*\mathrm{Vol} = \mathrm{Vol}$. Notice that in the case where $f$ is volume preserving in the measure sens by $f$ reverses orientation, then $f^*\mathrm{Vol} = -\mathrm{Vol}$ so the two notion are not exactly identical. I hope it is clearer !

Comment: And it means that all equal area map projections are local symplectomorphisms? See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721687/are-all-equal-area-map-projections-local-symplectomorphisms-or-not-all-of-them?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes on surfaces (because $\mathrm{Vol} = \omega$ in this case) but not in general. On $\mathbb{R}^4$ with $\omega = dx \wedge dy + dz \wedge dt$ and $f : (x,y,z,t) \mapsto (x + t,y,z,t)$ is a volume preserving diffeomorphism but doesn't preserve the sympectic form.